# How to run animation + callback function one time

Tags: jquery, function, callback

I want my function to run one time, so the h1 element will go to 45px one time and then use the callback function (changing the opacity to 0.2). And the same goes for mouseout

```
$("article.recensie").mouseover(function () { // vraag a

  $("article.recensie h1").animate({
    fontSize: '45px'
  }, 500,

  function () {
    $("article.recensie").animate({
        opacity: '0.2'
    }, 500);
  })
});

$("article.recensie").mouseout(function () {

  $("article.recensie h1").animate({
    fontSize: '40px'
  }, 250,

  function () {
    $("article.recensie").animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 500);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to animate css-properties, I suggest you use CSS3 instead of jQuery.

Examples & Explanations here:
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/#how2use

Working Sample here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/R8cFi9L9HRwlRypMVTlx

```
  article.recensie {
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  }

  article.recensie:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
    font-size: 45px;
  }
```

Comment: Could you describe what works and what doesn't in your current code?

Comment: The whole code works, but the problem is, when I hover over it one time, it keeps doing the animation instead of doing it once.

Comment: Your code works for me, check [this sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/5HJtRk07ckv0NSwGCFbR).